# Weak learner in scikit learn random forest and extra tree classifiers

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

In the paper "[Decision Forests for Classification, Regression, Density Estimation, Manifold Learning and Semi-Supervised Learning](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/155552/decisionForests_MSR_TR_2011_114.pdf)", the authors speak of different types of weak learners: axis-aligned hyperplane, general oriented hyperplane and quadratic.

Am I missing something or is the implementation in Scikit-Learn doing the equivalent of axis aligned at each split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, we are only doing axis-aligned splits. This is in fact the most common splitting strategy, giving in most of the cases good-enough results while not increasing computational complexity.